# App chooser is not displaying Phone app for Intent.ACTION_CALL in Android 6.0

Tags: android

In my android app i am trying to call on phone numbers without going to dialer.

So i am using following code to achieve so:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_number));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(callIntent, "Call..."));
```

I have also added the permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

This code works fine till Android 5.1 which shows all the calling Apps installed in the App chooser but on Android 6.0 onwards it shows either a blank chooser or the App chooser with Skype on it if installed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask for that permission on Run time from api 23 on.  Here's the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Ask for permission CALL_PHONE at runtime,it will work.